# How to start an Intent from an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, android-asynctask

I'm trying to start an Activity in my AsyncTask from the doInBackground() method but it doesn't seem to start.

I've passed the Activity of which I call the AsyncTask from using params[0].

```
    public class StartProcess extends AsyncTask<Main, Void, Main>
{
    @Override
    protected Main doInBackground(Main... params) { 

        return params[0];
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Main... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("post");
        Intent loc = new Intent(params[0],LocationHandler3.class);
        loc.putExtra("locationType",0);
        loc.putExtra("startEndType",0);
        params[0].startActivity(loc);
    }


}
```

Comment: use onpostexecute() method to do this.

Comment: @Akki Do I pass Main in the same way as I did before?

Comment: AsyncTask<Main, Void, Main>

instead of returning bull why dont you just return Main

Comment: @Akki I've edited my code above, which still doesn't work, not sure what you mean.

Comment: I'm passing in Main (which is the Activity I call the AsyncTask from) to be able to launch the intent.

Comment: use this

public class StartProcess extends AsyncTask<Main, Void, Main>
{
@Override
protected Main doInBackground(Main... params) {

return params[0];
}
protected void onPostExecute(Main params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println("post");
Intent loc = new Intent(params,LocationHandler3.class);
loc.putExtra("locationType",0);
loc.putExtra("startEndType",0);
startActivity(loc);
}


}

Comment: Thanks that worked. Although I had to add params.startActivity(loc); If you put your code into a proper answer below I'll accept it for you.

Comment: surething now the code is available as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this modified code.

```
    public class StartProcess extends AsyncTask<Main, Void, Main> {  
      @Override
        protected Main doInBackground(Main... params) { 
             return params[0]; 
       }
     protected void onPostExecute(Main params) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("post"); 
         Intent loc = new Intent(params,LocationHandler3.class); 
          loc.putExtra("locationType",0); 
          loc.putExtra("startEndType",0); 
          startActivity(loc);
    }
    }
```

Comment: This also solved my Looper.loop() problems. Don't need that anymore!

Answer (score 1):

```
   StartProcess objStartProcess= new StartProcess();
   objStartProcess.execute("");
```

Using `execute("")` You can call `doinBackground() method.`...And AsyncTask Complete in `OnPostExecute` Method So try to start Activity in ...